# Ubuntu 14.04 : how could i can identify the origin of a freeze

Tags: freeze

My Asus computer with an NVIDIA Geforce 425M graphic card freezes randomly. The only solution is to hard reset the computer.

How can I identify if the problem come from the graphic card or from the computer itself. When I boot the computer under Windows, i have never experienced problem.

Is there some logs i can look at or a trace i can activate?

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can always check out the syslog for further information about the system freeze.

It's located here

`/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 0):

Run a graphic card burn in test and  a memory (RAM) test and let it sit over night while testing, sometimes even though the results may pass the first couple of times, when the components become hot they will begin to fail.

Ubuntu Systems have been known to run hot, so definitely begin by testing your hardware and see where that takes you.